# How to share my youtube-playlist with the end user, using You Tube data api version 3 objective c

Tags: objective-c, youtube, google-api

i am developing an app on which i want, end user can access my youtube-playlist(and videos among them). i have the full access of the youtube channel, just want the users to access them. I am using objective c client library for youtube v3.
what i have done:

## auth 2 authentication for end user

## api call to youtube server using my client id and secret.

Currently i am getting Like, upload, watch history etc. of my channel from another user(end user) but only the id, not any link of video of related playlist.
When i login using my credential of youtube on my app i get all the video links, but when i login using another youtube id then i don't get the video links. can not figure it out why this is happening.

Basically i just want some suggestion or direction on the following:

## is it possible to share my youtube-playlist to others(end user)?

## if possible then can the user can access the videos of the channel? if so how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misunderstanding the concept. Any playlist/video that is publically visible on youtube, then just the ID for corresponding playlist/video is needed.

One has to make the query request to youtube server based on the ID of the resource he want to fetch.

Basically my Client ID and Secret are using on my app to get the details use of the app, meaning how much api is calling(you can get it on the console of your project).